# How do I make the second column of my tables wider?

Tags: html, css

```
table {
  padding: 0;
}

table tr {
   border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;
  background-color: #ffffff;
   margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
table tr:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}
table tr th {
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.375rem 0.8125rem;
}

table tr td {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.375rem 0.8125rem;
}
table tr th :first-child,
table tr td :first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
table tr th :last-child,
table tr td :last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

The above is my css.

```
<h2>Year 3: 2023</h2>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Lorem ipsum 1</th>
    <th>Lorem ipsum 2</th>
    <th>Lorem ipsum 3</th>
    <th>Lorem ipsum 4</th>
    <th>Lorem ipsum 5</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Dicta summo signiferumque cu pri</td>
    <td> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, persius convenire hendrerit nec at, impedit feugait pertinax mei ex. Ne erant reformidans sed. Blandit forensibus ex est, has repudiandae instructior eu, ut qui dicant accusamus ullamcorper. Qui an cetero placerat phaedrum, mel alia sale at. No pro ferri apeirian urbanitas, eos an unum detracto periculis, eos illum referrentur consequuntur at.</td>
    <td> Cu cum viris latine dignissim, ius populo legendos ad.</td>
    <td> Cu cum viris latine dignissim, ius populo legendos ad.</td>
    <td>Dicta summo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Dicta summo signiferumque cu pri</td>
    <td> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, persius convenire hendrerit nec at, impedit feugait pertinax mei ex. Ne erant reformidans sed. Blandit forensibus ex est, has repudiandae instructior eu, ut qui dicant accusamus ullamcorper. Qui an cetero placerat phaedrum, mel alia sale at. No pro ferri apeirian urbanitas, eos an unum detracto periculis, eos illum referrentur consequuntur at.</td>
    <td> Cu cum viris latine dignissim, ius populo legendos ad.</td>
    <td> Cu cum viris latine dignissim, ius populo legendos ad.</td>
    <td>Dicta summo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Dicta summo signiferumque cu pri</td>
    <td> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, persius convenire hendrerit nec at, impedit feugait pertinax mei ex. Ne erant reformidans sed. Blandit forensibus ex est, has repudiandae instructior eu, ut qui dicant accusamus ullamcorper. Qui an cetero placerat phaedrum, mel alia sale at. No pro ferri apeirian urbanitas, eos an unum detracto periculis, eos illum referrentur consequuntur at.</td>
    <td> Cu cum viris latine dignissim, ius populo legendos ad.</td>
    <td> Cu cum viris latine dignissim, ius populo legendos ad.</td>
    <td>Dicta summo</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The above is my HTML.

I am still pretty new to CSS and HTML so I'm a little confused. If I want to put most of my text in my second column, how do I make that one specifically wider? At the moment, when I run this code, it makes the second column very long vertically and it doesn't look great.

I am looking for something that looks like this codepen sandbox I created here: https://codepen.io/melonandthecoconut/pen/NWvqbKo. Picture here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3Tn3.png.

Comment: Can you add the HTML code also?

Comment: Hi, just added it.

Comment: you have the codepen, and if it is the intended way, why can't you use it on your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set width for each and every `<td>` in your table if you want. but in this particular case, if you need to make only the 2nd `<td>` wider, we can achieve that just using CSS `:nth-child()` pseudo-class.

```
table tr td:nth-child(2) {
   width: 40%;
   // just change this matches to your requirement.
}
```

the thing to remember when you using `:nth-child` is that we should use it on the **element**, not to the **parent element**

or else you can simply set the width property on the element like below with the style attribute.

```
<td style="width: 40%">
```

**update**
[working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-pine-h6kez?file=/index.html)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I am putting multiple tables on a page. When I do it like this, the first table looks perfect. Each table after has a varying level of the long text stretching it vertically and it looks very strange. Does this not work if you are trying to use multiple tables on the same page? Or how do you apply <td style="width: 40%"> specifically to each <td> element?

Comment: do you need to have similar-looking tables on the same page, like the same width for each snd `<td>` on each table?

Comment: Yes I was trying to create pretty much five identical tables. The text wouldn't be identical but the amount of text should be fairly similar across the five tables. The second column would have some variance in the amount of text ranging from 4-5 sentences to 10 sentences or so.

Comment: it should work with the current implementation though. can I see your entire HTML page?

Comment: I made a code sandbox to test it, it works perfect for me, will update the answer with the link, go check it out

Comment: Hi, I'm so sorry, looking at your sandbox, it was working as intended, but I was looking for something more like this: https://codepen.io/melonandthecoconut/pen/NWvqbKo. I copied the same code into there and the second column row is ideal. Picture here: https://i.imgur.com/VuH0Jsl.png. I'll add both to my original post Would you know how to do something like that? Thank you again for your help.

Comment: I didn't get your point! what exactly do you need to achieve?

Comment: I had a moment, it works perfectly, thank you!